# Array Index Is Out of Bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this method that checks a row based on what's in it.  I also have a static string array that is initialized with nothing in it.  I'm getting an out of bounds index error  which doesn't make any sense to me because I don't have a max length on the array.

**This is my method:**

```
private void PrintTable(DataTable table)
{ 
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        litCanCount.Text = "Canoe count is: ";
        litKayCount.Text = "Kayak count is: ";

        string currRow = row["CraftType"].ToString();
        if (currRow == CANOE)
        {
            Response.Write("CANOE INCREMENT!<br />");
            CANOEi++;
            txtCanCount.Text = CANOEi.ToString();
            arr[i] = currRow;
            i++;
        }
        if (currRow == KAYAK)
        {
            Response.Write("KAYAK INCREMENT!<br />");
            KAYAKi++;
            txtKayCount.Text = KAYAKi.ToString();
            arr[i] = currRow;
            i++;
        }
        for (int a = 0; arr.Length > a; a++)
        {
            Response.Write(arr[a] + "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the top piece of my class, with my static variables:**

```
public partial class Index: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string CANOE = "Canoe";
    string KAYAK = "Kayak";
    int CANOEi;
    int KAYAKi;
    string[] arr = new string[] { };
    int i = 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr`'s length is 0....

Comment: A global variable named `i`? I love it....

Comment: But in the method, I'm adding a string to the iTH element, and then incrementing i, right?

Comment: And you get the exception...

Comment: Is it possible to set arr[i] if the length of arr == 0?

Comment: @L.B I initialized the array to be any size of strings.  So why is it that when I go to enter a string into the first element (index 0) that it's saying out of bounds.

Comment: @user3267755 `I initialized the array to be any size of strings`. You think so. What you did is to create an array with zero size. So you can not access arr[0] (It would require a min length 1). Test it. `var arr2 = new string[] { }; arr2[0] = "";`

Comment: You would be better of using a List<string> instead of an array you can add to it instead of having a fixed size array

Comment: Surprisingly I can't find good canonical duplicate... So strange... Plenty of not-s-useful duplicates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you need that code. If you just want to show the count of canoe and kayak you could use an elementary call to [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    DataRow[] canoe = table.Select("CraftType = 'Canoe'");
    DataRow[] kayak = table.Select("CraftType = 'Kayak'");

    litCanCount.Text = "Canoe count is: " + canoe.Length;
    litKayCount.Text = "Kayak count is: " + kayak.Length;
```

If you think about it, a datatable is just a sophisticated array and the framework offers many methods to work with a datatable.

For example, in LINQ

```
int canoeNumber = table.AsEnumerable().Count(x => x["CraftType"].ToString() == "Canoe");
```

Comment: You saw past what I was trying to do and gave me a much easier and optimal solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays must be assigned a length

**Array with zero length (Runtime exception)**

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] arr = new string[] { }; //Array with no length
    arr[0] = "hi"; //Runtime exception
}
```

**Array with one length (No exceptions)**

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] arr = new string[1]; //Array with one length, index starts at zero
    arr[0] = "test";
}
```

If you want to use a collection without defining the size then consider using a list

**List Collection (no length definition needed)**

```
   List<string> listString = new List<string>();
   listString.Add("hi");
   listString.Add("bye");
   listString.Add("oh hai");
```

Comment: The first example compiles. Why wouldn't it? (You will get a runtime exception, but that doesn't preclude compilation.)

Comment: @PaulBinder: why is "not valid" comment there? There is nothing wrong with that particular line of code (apart from being weird). Even if it was, it would not be very helpful. It reads as "something is wrong" - not much help, is it? I'd remove it altogether.